# cannot resolve method holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to set in my recyclerview a value from a textview:

```
holder.textViewlikeTotal.setText(ab);
```

it works if it is inside

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

but I need to make it work inside my  `public void onClick(View v) {`

any ideas how to make holder work?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1

- in you RecyclerView.**ViewHolder** implements View.OnClickListener
- Implement onClick with: holder.textViewlikeTotal.setText(ab);

Step 2
 - in onBindViewHolder event, set click listener.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClick.Listener(){
         youButton.setOnClickListener(holder);
  );
}
```

:D